# Docker image is not visible when I run docker ps

Tags: docker, ansible

I have a dockerfile

```
FROM centos:7
MAINTAINER Kyle Day <kday@bstonetech.com>
RUN yum update -y
RUN yum install -y git https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm

RUN yum install -y ansible
RUN git clone https://github.com/kday92/dockerAnsible.git
RUN ansible-playbook "-e edit_url=andrewgarfield edit_alias=emmastone site_url=testing.com" dockerAnsible/dockerFileBootstrap.yml
RUN (cd /lib/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/; for i in *; do [ $i == systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service ] || rm -f $i; done); \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /etc/systemd/system/*.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/local-fs.target.wants/*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*udev*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*initctl*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/basic.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/anaconda.target.wants/*;

VOLUME [ "/sys/fs/cgroup" ]
EXPOSE 80 443 3306
CMD ["/usr/sbin/httpd", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

Whenever the dockerfile is built, I run the command `docker run -d -P -i -t 02872c9ce405`, but it does not display when I type `docker ps`.  The ansible playbook that is being run inside of the docker build is here -

https://github.com/kday92/dockerAnsible/blob/master/dockerFileBootstrap.yml

The docker container builds successfully with no errors, and then when I go to run that docker run command no container appears.

How can I determine what the issue is?  No error output is being shown anywhere.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
docker ps
```

lists running containers, not images. if you want to see also stopped containers type

```
docker ps -a
```

if you want to see the images type

```
docker images
```

basics!

Comment: Thats the thing, I use `docker ps` after ive already run `docker run -d -P -i -t 02872c9ce405`.  I believe that commnand is supposed to start the docker container.  That code that I am putting in there is what appears when I do `docker images`

Comment: The issue was that there was a discrepancy between the Dockerfile on git, and the dockerfile in my local.